# Formatting strins to show special characters

Tags: android, string

I am sending some messages to the server, from the phone. But, when I send it, the special characters like ó, í, etc. are not sent ok, I see "?" instead of the character. Here I take the message:

```
chatmensaje=text.getText().toString();
                    chatmensaje=chatmensaje.trim();
                    vaciarChat();
                    params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.clear();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mensaje", "Personal: "+chatmensaje));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subnotid", String.valueOf(General.subnotid)));
                    try {
                        CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(urlchat, params);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run(){

                                if(chatmensaje != ""){
                                General.mensajes.add(chatmensaje);
                                //text.setText("");


                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        madapter = new MessageAdapter(
                                                getApplicationContext(), 0, General.mensajes);
                                        setListAdapter(madapter);
                                        madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }

                                });
                                }
                                    }
                            });
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        General.chatnotsent.add(chatmensaje);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        General.chatnotsent.add(chatmensaje);
                    }

                }
```

"text" is an EditText. How could I format the String to the special characters are shown well? Thanks.

Comment: Does the string `chatmensaje` contain such special characters ?

Comment: Yes, its the message its going to be sent, I know I should format that String, but I don't know how...

Comment: Deleted my  answer as Kumar's solution will  solve your issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** You will need to use `UrlEncodedFormEntity`.

**Eg:**

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mensaje", "Personal: "+chatmensaje));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subnotid", General.subnotid+""));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Excellent solution kumar, didn't even think about it . Up Voted .

Comment: Thank you..... actually this code is close to my heart...as this was the first code that i wrote on my first programming job.

Answer (score 0):

For special character we use the Unicode definition, for the '&' for example: \u0026 if I am correct. Here is a nice reference page: http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=0
try with this

Comment: So, loop the string and change the special characters for the code of every single special character?

Comment: @Fustigador yes. read below useful post. Try put they as HTML.

String htmlStringWithMathSymbols = "&#8804;  &#8805;";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlStringWithMathSymbols));

Here you can display your math symbol in textView

Here the post http://www.hrupin.com/2011/12/how-to-put-some-special-math-symbols-in-textview-editview-or-other-android-ui-element